# Using a Random Forest for Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, random-forest

This is a simple question, is it okay to use a Random Forest model on Time Series Data? I ask this because, in a random forest model, we perform bootstrapping of observations where we randomly sample from the training set with replacement. Doesn't this ruin the "ordering of observations" in the model, since it being time series data. 
I'm asking this with context to financial data, say I'm doing a classification type problem to buy/not buy an asset, and I collect daily data for some features to predict this variable.

Answer (score 16):

It works well but only if the features are properly prepared so that the order of the lines is not important anymore.

E.g. for a univariate time series $y_i$, you would use $y_i$ as response and e.g. the following features:

1. Lagged versions $y_{i-1}$, $y_{i-2}$, $y_{i-3}$ etc.
2. Differences of appropriate order, e.g.  $y_{i-1} - y_{i-2}$, $y_{i-1} - y_{i-8}$ (if there is weekly seasonality expected and the observations occur daily) etc.
3. Integer or dummy coded periodic time info such as month in year, week day, hour of day, minute in hour etc.

The same approach works for different modelling techniques, including linear regression, neural nets, boosted trees etc.

An example is the following (using a binary target "temperature increase" (y/n)):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ranger)
library(MetricsWeighted) # AUC

# Import
raw <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/daily-min-temperatures.csv")

# Explore
str(raw)
head(raw)
summary(raw)
hist(raw$Temp, breaks = "FD")

# Prepare and add binary response
prep <- raw %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date),
         y = year(Date),
         m = month(Date),
         d = day(Date),
         increase = 0 + (Temp > lag(Temp)))

with(prep, table(y))
summary(prep)

# Plot full data -> year as seasonality
ggplot(data = prep, aes(x = Date, y = Temp))+
  geom_line(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) +
  scale_x_date()

# No visible within year seasonality
prep %>% 
  filter(y == 1987) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Temp))+
  geom_line(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) +
  scale_x_date()

# Add some lags and diffs & remove incomplete rows
prep <- prep %>% 
  mutate(lag1 = lag(Temp),
         lag2 = lag(Temp, 2L),
         lag3 = lag(Temp, 3L),
         dif1 = lag1 - lag2,
         dif2 = lag2 - lag3) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.))

# Train/valid split in blocks
valid <- prep %>% 
  filter(y == 1990)
train <- prep %>% 
  filter(y < 1990)

# Models
y <- "increase" # response
x <- c("lag1", "lag2", "lag3", "dif1", "dif2", "y", "m", "d") # covariables
form <- reformulate(x, y)

# Logistic model: Linear dependence between difs and lags
fit_glm <- glm(form, 
               data = train, 
               family = binomial()) 
summary(fit_glm)

# Random forest
fit_rf <- ranger(form, 
                 data = train,
                 seed = 345345, 
                 importance = "impurity", 
                 probability = TRUE)
fit_rf
barplot(-sort(-importance(fit_rf))) # Variable importance

# Evaluate on 1990 for glm by looking at ROC AUC
pred_glm <- predict(fit_glm, valid, type = "response")
AUC(valid[[y]], pred_glm) # 0.684 ROC AUC

# Then for rf
pred_rf <- predict(fit_rf, valid)$predictions[, 2]
AUC(valid[[y]], pred_rf)    # 0.702 ROC AUC

# view OOB residuals of rf within one month to see if structure is left over
random_month <- train %>% 
  mutate(residuals = increase - fit_rf$predictions[, 2]) %>% 
  filter(y == 1987, m == 3) 

ggplot(random_month, aes(x = Date, y = residuals))+
  geom_line(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2) +
  scale_x_date()
```

Replacing variables "y" and "m" by factors would probably improve the logistic regression. But since the question was about random forests, I leave this to the reader.

Comment: "but only if the features are properly prepared so that the order of the lines is not important anymore." If I understand you correctly, you basically need to calculate all the lagged versions to be features, so the order of the lines is no longer important?

Comment: Yes exactly: Lags, differences etc.

Comment: @MichaelM - I have two quick questions; when entering data for lagged versions, what do you do when there is not a value (for example, y_i-2 for y_i)? Would it be a NaN, 0...? Also, is there any place where I could find an example of how to handle the differences? I am not sure I understand what I am trying to do there.

Comment: I'd probably remove the few lines without lag. By differences I mean those between different lagged versions of the time series. So e.g. if you have hourly values $y_{i}$ of river temperatures, you can use $y_{i-1}$, $y_{i-2}$, $y_{i-24}$, $y_{i-1} - y_{i-24}$ and $y_{i-1} - y_{i-2}$ as predictors. This example is for a univariate series.

Comment: @MichaelM - I am also working with univariate series, adding lagged versions (columns $y_i-1$ to $y_i-n$) for all rows. (Sorry, still figuring out how to do subscripts correctly as i-1 and i-n are supposed to be subscripts). For the differences, I have data that is taken once a day, but there is no cyclic periodicity. How would these needs to be handled? Is there a concrete example online that I could maybe follow? Thanks!

Comment: You need to put curly brackets like x_{t-1} (tex style). Is there a publicly available data set (e.g. in R) you want me to create a realistic example for?

Comment: @MichaelM - Thank you, I will take as little of your time as possible! If you had [this day/temperature data set](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/daily-min-temperatures.csv), for example, how would you remove time dependencies? Giving me just a few rows would be enough. Thanks again!

Comment: Also - Just to give you more details, in my particular case I am dealing with a classification problem, which would be the equivalent of trying to predict whether the temperature will increase or decrease. Since, of course, I have the temperature column for training, I have created an extra column for the label, which is True if the temperature for $y_{i}$ >= $y_{i-1}$ and False otherwise. I imagine this means that the temperature column itself would not be used as a feature for training after the label is created.

Comment: I have tried to add this example with binary response.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will translate it to Python and will let you know if I have any more questions. You've been so helpful!

Answer (score 4):

A random forest would not be expected to perform well on time series data for a variety of reasons. In my view the greatest pitfalls are unrelated to the bootstrapping, however, and are not unique to random forests:

1. Time series have an interdependence between observations, which the model will ignore.
2. The underlying learner is typically a tree based algorithm, which does not extrapolate trends. If there are genuine time trends in the data these will not be projected forward.

Comment: Random Forest can be, and is used for time-series predictions. Look at a few examples: Dudek, G. (2015). Short-term load forecasting using random forests. In Intelligent Systems' 2014 (pp. 821-828). Springer, Cham./// Mei, J., He, D., Harley, R., Habetler, T., & Qu, G. (2014, July). A random forest method for real-time price forecasting in New York electricity market. In 2014 IEEE PES General Meeting| Conference & Exposition (pp. 1-5). IEEE.

Comment: @MichaelM how  does RF deal with features like multiple level shifts and/or multiple deterministic time trends. Does one have to specify them. How about the window of response around holidays with each holiday having its own pattern ?